# Is it possible to make a distributable Vue widget with Single File Components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

This might be a bit of an odd question, but I'll try to explain.

I'm looking to build a vue based video player widget for a client's Drupal website. The idea is to create something he can just drop in, like a JQuery plugin. However, I'd really like to leverage Vue's Single File Components (with Webpack) so I can keep everything all bundled together.

My first thought would be to use the Vue CLI, `npm build` and then reach into the **dist/** folder and pull out the following to drop in:

```
<link href=/static/css/app.cf6f127cf50f4c0b2424d30fdc56c3a4.css rel=stylesheet>

<div id="my-widget"></div>

<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.e12c1c4a9566f686d69f.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.47037dd92c40b3f38949.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.3f1bab5cc5b1be1127b2.js></script>
```

---

Although this feels off, is there a better way to achieve this? Keep in mind his website is NOT a Vue app, but I want this widget to be built LIKE a Vue app.

Comment: You can develop your video player as Vue plugin, then like JQuery, import `vue.js`, `vue.plugin-name.js`

Comment: CLI 3.0 allows you to build as a library or web component, check https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library to see if they suit your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @yuriy636 for answering my question. The CLI 3.0 allows to build as a library or a web component. [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library)

Also I found the following article which goes into more depth

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand 100 percent, as far as I know, it is possible. It doesn't matter how you bundle your app. It is a matter of architecture. You can use vue.js partly, like widget.

First when you set Vue instance, just set element with your target element.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#my-widget'
});
```

If you want your client to set element himself, make some functions to create vue widget. (considering multiple vue instance or state sharing blah blah...)

```
// you can provide simple function like this (I'm sure it needs to be more.)
const Widget = {
    createWidget(el) {
        new Vue({
            el: el
        });
    }
};

// on client side
Widget.createWidget('#his-widget');
```

On bundling, if you want your widget to be bundled together with client's Drupal website. Let him import your widget like other libraries. You can build your widget with `npm run build` in vue-cli and then give it to him so that he can include it.

Comment: Could this methods be used to create multiple different Vue widgets on one page?